# SQL How to convert number (integer) to date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm working with small commerce software and importing to SQL Server. But there are numbers:

```
75739
76910
73105
75821
75245
75605
77169
73265
75611
74073
77012
```

which represent the date I think.

How to convert these numbers to date `YYYY-MM-DD` and `YYYYMMDD`?

Comment: What dates should these represent?

Comment: I don't now... I just got Files

Comment: Without some sort of mapping between these numbers and dates, we can't help - ask the people you got the files from.

Comment: These dates are not SQL server dates converted to int. For example cast(75739 as datetime) -> May, 15 2107. So what date 75739 is ?

Comment: Probably ticks from an unknown datetime

Comment: Ok, i need to find out real dates, because now it's not imposible

Comment: If I had to guess, these are number of days since 1/1/1800.  @Justin, if you know what a specific date is in this format, then you can easily get the base date for the conversion.

Comment: How do you expect to parse those numbers into dates if you aren't even sure they represent dates?

Answer (score 5):

Based on the SQL Server epoch (base or zero date) of 01 Jan 1900, these dates are in 22nd century

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, 75739, 0) -- 2107-05-15 00:00:00.000
```

Or are they based on the lower bound of datetime? This is 1960-ish, which works for date of births

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, 75739, '17530101') -- 1960-05-15 00:00:00.000
```

tl;dr more info needed. Otherwise don't even try

Answer (score 1):

In general, when dates are represented as numbers, then they represent days since a given day.  In some caes, you might have a number like 20120829, which actually can be parsed as YYYYMMDD.  But these dates do not appear to be in that form.  Another format could be like YYday-of-year, so 100001 would be Jan 1, 2010.  However, these dates don't appear in that format either.

Assume these are days since a given date, then in SQL Server you would use:

```
select dateadd(day, <val>, <basedate>)
```

For Excel, you would use someting like:

```
select dateadd(day, <val>, '1899-12-31')
```

However, that puts these dates in the 22nd century.

You need to learn more about the formatting of these dates.