# Convert Integer to Date

Tags: sql, excel

I have tried numerous ways both in SQL and Excel to convert an Integer to a date.

This is what I have:

The number shown in SQL is 79176. The program shows this date is supposed to be 10-07-2017 (mm-dd-yyyy).

Can you please tell me how to convert this to show this as a date. either in Excel or in SQL to print this report.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
select CONVERT (datetime,20100101)
SELECT FORMAT( [date], 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'en-US' ) AS 'DateTime Result'  
       ,FORMAT(123456789,'###-##-####') AS 'Custom Number Result';
```

1. You can refer to how [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855867/convert-int-to-datetime-sql)
2. After converting to datetime, you can refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to convert to the desired format

Comment: I am trying to follow this and the link you provided but as a newbie it is not making sense to me.
The Code I have is this:
`code`
Select * FROM DATABASE.dbo.[user]
Select Convert (datetime,20100101)
Select Format("[user].PasswordDate", 'dd/MM/YYYY', 'en-us') AS 'DateTime Result'
,Format(123456789,'###-##-####') AS 'Custom Number Result';
`code`

Comment: Sorry I did not read carefully. [79176] seems to be the number of days. Refer to the link below, hoping to help you.
SELECT DATEADD(day, 75739, 0) -- 2107-05-15 00:00:00.000
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179331/sql-how-to-convert-number-integer-to-date

Comment: Thank you for that. I searched and searched and that article never came up.  If I use the date add (took the date it equals and subtract that number of days 10-7-2017 - 79176) I get Dec 28, 1800.  Seems like an odd day to start from.  I will test this with a few other known variables in the morning.